# Jetpack Compose blink animation by animateFloatAsState stuck at invisible state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation

I've created this composable so that when I update the text, the text view will blink.
I want it to first hide, then update display text, finally show.

In some scenario, the "updated" value might be the same as the old value so I add a timestamp to force an update from the data source. In my case the timestamp's precision is to second.

It works fine for a while, then it sometimes get stuck into invisible state.

Is this cause by update while an animation is in-flight? How could I solve this problem?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun BlinkTextView(modifier:Modifier = Modifier, text: String, timestamp: Instant?)
{
    var displayValue by remember {mutableStateOf(text)}
    var lastUpdate by remember { mutableStateOf(timestamp)}

    val alpha by animateFloatAsState(targetValue = if(displayValue != text || timestamp != lastUpdate) 0f else 1f, label = "BlinkTextView"){
        displayValue = text
        lastUpdate = timestamp
    }

    Text(modifier = modifier.alpha(alpha), text = text)
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide the code which calls the BlinkTextView Composable and updates the Instant on a second intervals?

Answer (score 1):

Try with AnimatedVisibility and LaunchedEffect

Here is an example:

```
const val BlinkTime = 50

@Composable
fun BlinkTextView(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    var visible by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }
    
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = text) {
        visible = false
        delay(BlinkTime.milliseconds)
        visible = true
    }

    AnimatedVisibility(
        modifier = modifier,
        visible = visible,
        enter = fadeIn(animationSpec = TweenSpec(durationMillis = 0)),
        exit = fadeOut(animationSpec = TweenSpec(durationMillis = 0))
    ) {
        Text(modifier = Modifier, text = text)
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
@Composable
fun BlinkTextViewUsage() {
    var myText by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(20.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        TextField(value = myText, onValueChange = { myText = it })

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        BlinkTextView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            text = myText
        )
    }
}
```